# appengine version today 7.12.12 -java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an google-app-engine project that use javafx.
I have installed the google plugin for eclipse and was using this versions of libraries :
appengine library -1.7.3
java jdk-1.7.0_01

when i was running locally everything runs great, but when i deploy i got this error from the app engine log :`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/myproj/MyServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`

i know what does it means , that my local compile is on a newest version then the appengine that why the app engine jre crushes.

what i cannot get is why for g-o-d is the current version of the google jdk?
Which version do you use, cause i must use 1.7 for other libraries in my project

the google app engine documentation site is really not updated :(

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine uses JDK 6 in production as of 1.7.3. While future support for JDK 7 [has been announced](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/10/app-engine-173-released.html), currently it's only supported locally.